# Vectorizing kernel code

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to implement the following in vectorized form

```
def kfunc(x,y):
   return #some number
def compute_K(X, kfunc):
    m, n = X.shape
    kernel = np.zeros((m, m))
    for i, row in enumerate(X):
        for j, ele in enumerate(row):
            for k, ele_2 in enumerate(row):
                kernel[j, k] = kfunc(ele, ele_2)
    return kernel
```

Basically, above takes in a numpy matrix and some function and compute the kernel matrix on matrix X

Comment: The content of kfunc is key to determining if and how such a function could be vectorized.

Comment: It looks like you overwrite `kernel` for each row, which means you could do `i = len(X) - 1` and `row = X[-1]` and eliminate the outer loop!

Comment: The fact that you are throwing away most of the `i` values is suspicious.  Beyond that I'd focus on rewriting `kfunc` so it can take 2 arrays (`row`), rather than 2 scalars.